# Theme Sherlock Dialog API 10

Tags: android, xml, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I've been testing my app on API 10 and a couple of views seem to to be different.

Firstly, the background of all dialog boxes seem to be black when they should be white as on the new APIS:

[image]

Secondly, the text for the the tabs are dark grey as opposed to white on the newer APIS:

[image]

How do I change the XML themes to keep it consistent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the abs_attrs.xml file in the ActionBarSherlock library, you'll see that the themes have a bunch of name-value pairs for all kinds of attributes.  You need to find the name-value pairs that are used in the dialog.  Usually the names are pretty self explanatory and you can see how these attributes are used in the abs_theme.xml file.

All you need to do is override (add them your app's theme) the appropriate attributes.  If you haven't themed ABS before, you should read a bit of the documentation on "mirroring" http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html.